# How to run python in exe window

Tags: python

I have a python code file named testcode.py and I have open a python.exe window open in order to run the code. I read online that I would run the code by putting

```
python testcode.py
```

into the exe window but it is saying that a syntax error and points to the name of my py file. Is there a reason why this is happening? Does the py file need to be saved in a certain place?

Comment: Run `python testcode.py` in your command prompt, NOT in python...

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because you're trying to run shell code in the Python interpreter. Open a CMD or PowerShell window and run `python testcode.py` there.